# except first item in list - python

Tags: python, list

I have string:

```
n = 'my fancy extension'
```

with

```
  ''.join([ x.capitalize() for x in n.split() ])
```

I get `MyFancyExtension`, but I need `myFancyExtension`.

How do I avoid capitalizing the first item in list, or not capitalizing at all if one word only specified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> n = 'my fancy extension'
>>> array = n.split()
>>> array[0] + ''.join(map(str.capitalize, array[1:]))
'myFancyExtension'
```

Comment: n="onewordwithnospace"

Comment: @meshy very elegant solution! so, there is nothing in python so I could say `''.join([ x.capitalize() for x in l --if x not first elmnt-- ])`, part between `--` being some index test?

Comment: Thank you! There may well be, but I can't think of it at the moment. If something occurs to me I'll surely update this `:)`

Comment: I've posted just such a solution below :) Python's ternary can be applied to the 'x for x in my_iterable' list comprehension in a few different places.

Comment: Yeah, that does the trick! I'm going to hold out for something more terse though `:)`

Answer (score 3):

In python 3 you can do:

```
n = 'my fancy extension'

first,*rest = n.split()

''.join([first] + [x.capitalize() for x in rest])
Out[10]: 'myFancyExtension'
```

python 2 doesn't have the fancy [extended tuple unpacking](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) syntax, so you'd need an extra step (oh no!):

```
spl = n.split()

first,rest = spl[0],spl[1:]
```

Comment: elegant also, just not so nice with python2, and thats what I'm using. thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Not a fan of dense one-liners, but:

```
>>> words = "my fancy extension"
>>> ''.join([x.capitalize() if i else x for (i, x) in enumerate(words.split())])
'myFancyExtension'
```

Answer (score 2):

> so, there is nothing in python so I could say ''.join([
>   x.capitalize() for x in l --if x not first elmnt-- ]), part between --
>   being some index test?

Actually you can use Python's ternary to achieve such an effect:

```
x if Condition else y
```

Or, in this case,

```
x.capitalize() if Condition else x.lower()
```

For example:

```
>>> def camel(my_string):
...     my_list = my_string.split()
...     return ''.join([x.lower() if x is my_list[0] else x.capitalize() for x in my_list])
>>> camel("lovely to be here")
'lovelyToBeHere'
```

Where 'x' is a string piece, 'condition' is `if x is my_list[0]`, and the two options are of course `x.lower()` and `x.capitalize()`.

Also kind of nice because if you goof up the first part it will lowercase it for you :)

```
>>> camel("WHat is the problem")
'whatIsTheProblem'
>>>
```

In most languages it's written as `if Condition x else y` order, instead of `x if Condition else y` so a lot of Python folk shy away from it, but personally I think Python's ternary is cool.

Comment: nicely explained, I will have that in mind for a future tasks. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
l = n.split()
if len(l)>1:
  print l[0] + ''.join([ x.capitalize() for x in l[1:] ])
else:
  print l[0]
```

or

```
import re
print re.sub(" ([a-z])", lambda s: s.group(1).upper(), n)
```

Comment: is it possible to have some more idiomatic way of doing that? anyway thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: please define idiomatic

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 'my fancy extension'

n = n.title()
n = n.replace(" ", "")
n = n[0].lower() + n[1:]

print(n)
```